# Is the perimeter of a square isometric to the circle? Homeomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

An isometry is defined as a function that preserves distances between points two metric spaces.

If make a circle with the same perimeter/circumference as the square, is it possible to find an explicit isometry between the two sets?

As for homeomorphic, I can visualize a homeomorphism, but again, I cannot find an explicit function between the square and circle that is bicontinuous and bijective.

Comment: You need to say what your metrics are. :) Particularly, do you mean "smallest length along the curve" (in which case "yes, the two are isometric") or something like chordal distance in the plane (in which case "no, they're not isometric")? To construct a homeomorphism, you might try to parametrize the square in polar coordinates.

Comment: Right, the problem was vague. I think the problem did mean "smallest length along the curve."

Comment: And by parametrize the square in polar coordinates do you mean, for each $\theta$, $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, reassign the corresponding point on the square to a point on the circle?

Comment: In prosaic terms, it suffices to write down a ($2\pi$-periodic) function $f:\mathbf{R} \to (0, \infty)$ whose polar graph $r = f(\theta)$ traces the square. (It's easy to make a suitable piecewise definition, and to check continuity.:) Alternatively, it's easy to write down the continuous "radial projection" mapping from the punctured plane to the circle, and to check that the restriction to the square is a bijection.

Answer (score 2):

If the metric is minimal distance along the curve, then you find a isometric mapping by simply walking each curve with the same speed.

Answer (score -1):

Isometric? No. Homeomorphic? Yes. Remember isometry is a distance preserving bijection.

Comment: I should specify that the metric is "the distance along the curve." Why can't they be isometric? Intuitively, and visually, I thought there'd be a distance preserving bijection.

Answer (score -1):

Not isometric because both lengths and angles need to be preserved in a given metric. But homeomorphic ok.

Comment: Where does the notion of angles come from? The text I used defines an isometry as a bijection $f: A \rightarrow B$ that preserves distances in the sense that for all $p,q \in A, d_A (p,q) = d_B (fp,fq)$. Unless there's an equivalent definition involving angles, doesn't it suffice to find this bijection?

Comment: @agrasin: Angles are defined indirectly as *ratios of distances*. If lengths alone are conserved  then it is *not* isometry.