# Homeomorphism and isometry

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, isometry

I have two questions about homeomorphism and isometry.

First, I know that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are not homeomorphic, but the proof that I know use the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$. My question is: *is there another proof with a different argument*? The cardinality is another aspect that differentiates $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ so, should a homeomorphism preserves the cardinality? If yes, just a reference for some proof is enough.

Second, the square and circle (viewed as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$) are homeomorphic (we can use the poolar coodinates to get a homeomorphism). But *are they isometric* (with the standard metric of $\mathbb{R}^2$)?

Comment: Being a bijection, a homeomorphism preserves cardinality.

Comment: A homeomorphism is a bijection, so yes, it must preserve cardinality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the perimeter of a square isometric to the circle? Homeomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209168/is-the-perimeter-of-a-square-isometric-to-the-circle-homeomorphic)

Comment: @DonThousand I think no. If I get the comments in questions, are given two different metrics as example of homeomorphism and no homeomorphism. I want to try to check using euclidean metric

Comment: @Greg Look at the other answers. They tell you that the answer is no via the euclidean metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A square is never isometric to a circle.

For any point $P$ in a (bounded) metric spaces $(M,d)$, we can consider the "furthest distance from $P$", i.e. the quantity $f(P)=\sup_{Q\in M}d(P,Q)$.

For a circle, the value of $f(P)$ is the same for all $P$, while for a square, $f(P)$ is not always the same.

---

As to the proof that $\Bbb Q$ is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, of course you can use the cardinality argument. Besides, there are other possibilities: for example, $\Bbb Q$ is disconnected, as it can be written as a disjoint union of two open sets $\{x:x^2<2\}$ and $\{x:x^2>2\}$, while $\Bbb R$ is connected.